Worms inside sunflower leaf

Hello,
I noticed a dark spot at the edge of one of my sunflower leafs and it appeared that the outer skin was raised like a blister. I decided to open it and I found a tiny worm/larvae inside. As I peeled back more I found a few more worm/larvae. I smashed them all but I'm curious as to what these are. They look white on one end and black at the other. Found another spot on another sunflower and this one only had one worm. Any ideas what these are and how to get rid of them or prevent them?

those are not worms ... they are caterpillars

These look like the maggots of leafminer flies. As their name suggests, the maggots bore into leaves and eat the spongy tissue in between the top and bottom surfaces. Not a huge problem in small numbers but if things get out of hand, squish the maggots in the leaves when you see the spots appear.
